# Multiple Counts with single query using Aggregates.match

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to Java and Mongodb. Can any one convert following mongodb query into java code

```
     db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "Total": [
      { "$match" : { "ReleaseDate": { "$exists": true }}},
      { "$count": "Total" },
    ],
    "Released": [
      { "$match" : {"ReleaseDate": { "$exists": true, "$nin": [""] }}},
      { "$count": "Released" }
    ],
    "Unreleased": [
      { "$match" : {"ReleaseDate": { "$exists": true, "$in": [""] }}},
      { "$count": "Unreleased" }
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "Total": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$Total.Total", 0] },
    "Released": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$Released.Released", 0] },
    "Unreleased": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$Unreleased.Unreleased", 0] }
  }}
])
```

like below terminology

```
 return Flowable.fromPublisher(
        propertyMongoService.getPropertyCollection().aggregate(
           Arrays.asList(
              Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("contactsVerified", false)), Aggregates.group("allFalse", Accumulators.sum("count", 1))
            )
        )
     ).firstElement()
```

I should use facet along with aggregates like Aggregates.facet(......)
we are using groovy+mongo+com.mongodb.reactivestreams